# Как вывести список из json

Tags: python, json

```py
with open("data.json", "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    d = json.load(f)

x = {
    'name': d,
    'leader_name': d,
    'leader_discord_id': d,
    'leader_vk': d
}
print(x)
```

Мне нужно вывести `name` - все данные что есть в файле.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы дать корректный ответ, необходимо знать структуру, которая хранится в переменной `d`. Для python в этой переменной будет храниться понятный тип данных, скорей всего словарь.

Допустим, что `d` имеет следующую структуру

```py
d = {
    "meta": {
        "version": 1
    },
    "organizations": [
        {
            "name": "Dani", "leader_name": "leader 1"
        },
        {
            "name": "Alex", "leader_name": "leader 2"
        },
        {
            "name": "Jane", "leader_name": "leader 3"
        }
    ]
}
```

Тогда, вам необходимо пробежаться по всем данным под ключом `organizations` и собрать все в списки, пример для наглядности, но он вполне рабочий

```py
names = [item["name"] for item in d["organizations"]]
leaders_name = [item["leader_name"] for item in d["organizations"]]
leader_discord_id = [item["leader_discord_id"] for item in d["organizations"]]
leader_vk = [item["leader_vk"] for item in d["organizations"]]
x = {
    'name': names,
    'leader_name': leaders_name,
    'leader_discord_id': leader_discord_id,
    'leader_vk': leader_vk
}
print(x)
```

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/UPgJIQJ

Comment: @KaigakuKibutsuji о чем я собственно и утверждаю в начале ответа. подогнал под вашу структуру

Comment: Спасибо, а как вывести сообщение без ": ['"

Comment: `print(*names)`